# I am trying to renew my NJ Drivers License

Tags: traffic

I am trying to renew my NJ Drivers License but have problems regarding proof of address. I am  a Catholic Priest who belongs to a Religious Order, ( the Franciscans) and I do not have a credit card or have a bank account and my housing is provided by my religious community. I pay no bills so I do not have these for verification of my address- I meet the 6 point ID verification with my current NJ License (4points) and my DD 214 military discharge papers (2points) The problem is proving where I live - I am unable to renew my license by mail as the renewal form says I need to renew at the DMV. Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated

Comment: A letter from the top official of the Franciscans at the address where you reside on official letterhead (if you have it) clearly noting his title and explaining your situation might work. You might also ask the same person how other members of your order have handled this in the past. Surely, you aren't the first Priest to have to deal with the NJ DMV.

Comment: thanks so much for that suggestion - We are going that route with a official letter from my superior - most priests in religious orders do have at least a credit card and a checking account if they are in leadership positions, pastor, religious superior, etc - My situation is not unique, but rare these days when you need a credit card for almost everything -airline, car and hotel rooms etc... I will continue to keep checking - I stumbled on this site and am grateful to have found out - thanks for taking time to respond -

Comment: This is a very interesting question that I do not know the answer to.  This raises the question in my mind - how are homeless people supposed to get a drivers license? My state has recently implemented "RealID".  We can continue to get a non-RealID compliant license in the old way - including renewing by mail.  To get a ReadID compliant license, we need additional proofs.  Is it possible for you to renew your drivers license without upgrading to a "RealID" compliant license and avoid triggering these additional requirements?

Comment: @emory the last time I checked (a year or two ago), New Jersey did not have a non-Real-ID option.

Comment: That is unfortunate.  I know that many poor people have trouble assembling the documents required for the non real id license.  The real id license will be oit of reach for so many people.

Comment: Semi off-topic: Maybe it really _is_ time for a national ID card? It's a politically sensitive topic, but it does make things easier (speaking as a German, where ID cards are mandatory).

Answer (score 2):

The current [New Jersey MVC website](https://www.state.nj.us/mvc/license/docselector/doc_address.htm) lists the following options for proof of address:

> Utility or credit card bill issued in the past 90 days that shows your name at your current address
>
> Checking or savings account statement from a bank or credit union, issued in the past 60 days
>
> High school or college report card or transcript containing your address, issued within the past two years
>
> Original lease or rental agreement showing your name as the lessee or renter
>
> Property tax bill, statement or receipt from the past year
>
> Any letter or correspondence (including tax bills) received from the IRS or state tax office in the last year
>
> First-class mail received from any federal, state or local government agency in the past six months

As you describe your situation, the first five don't apply, but if your driver's license renewal notice was sent by mail, that counts as "first-class mail received from any federal, state or local government agency in the past six months".

The website also notes that this list is not comprehensive, and other methods of proving your address are possible.  If all else fails, you can contact them for suggestions.